# Garmin devices data reading via BLE using native android/iOS app

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, garmin

My requirement is to communicate with any of the Garmin device(which has BLE support) with my native android app. I have already developed an android app which can connect with Wahoo Tickers (using their android sdk)and users can directly read data from ticker (no need to install their official app).

So far my research, Garmin have Connect IQ SDK which has a mandatory requirement of installing [Garmin Connect™ Mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.garmin.android.apps.connectmobile&feature=search_result&hl=en) app.

Is it possible to connect/pair with the Garmin devices using Android/iOS Core 
Bluetooth API (without even using their sdk and app)?

Unfortunately I don't have any Garmin device yet. After this research I will purchase one for real testing.

Any link or answer will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: "To communicate with a Connect IQ device via your companion application, users must also install Garmin Connect Mobile™ onto their phones. All communication for companion applications running on Android goes through a Garmin Connect Mobile service to reach the device.

When initializing the SDK, this requirement is checked and initialization will fail if Garmin Connect Mobile is not installed. " it in the SDK manual https://developer.garmin.com/connect-iq/programmers-guide/android-sdk-guide/

Comment: I don't think it is possible. You must register to Garmin developer and get license key. Then only you will be able to pair it using their SDK.